# Parse error on make_integrated_address

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, payment-id, integrated-address

I am getting "Parse error" on a `make_integrated_address` request. How do I fix it?

I generated the payment ID using this command in the terminal : `openssl rand 32 -hex`

The error looks like this:

```
{"error": {"code": -32700, "message": "Parse error"}, "id": 0, "jsonrpc": "2.0"}
```

My request is:

```
string str = "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":\"0\",\"method\":\"make_integrated_address\",\"params\":{\"standard_address\":\"myaddress\",payment_id:\"1027188273c9f2e53131e303404b6e7d9d3ead01d70ca258d0fa63cb6fd14b93\"}}";

string gg = GetResponse (str);
return gg;
```

Answer (score 1):

The payment ID you are trying to use is too long (32 bytes, when it should be 8 bytes).

From the [documentation](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#make_integrated_address):

```
payment_id - string; (Optional, defaults to a random ID) 16 characters hex encoded.
```

Example call:

```
 curl -sd '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0", "method":"make_integrated_address","params": {"payment_id":"5b67d705bbf72c77"}}' http://localhost:28084/json_rpc
```

And response:

```
{
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "integrated_address": "A8mA7fFvCnjhmoNQpCrDBQXFM25rqFBZYBq8RepazSLSBwsj5kRtuM9iCSuz3vs9KbfZhrQj1BKRxVCpyqii7pca5EzinX4GnyZEXS34vk",
    "payment_id": "5b67d705bbf72c77"
  }
}
```

@user36303 also correctly points out you have not quoted the parameter name `payment_id`.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected it. But still getting the same error. New payment id : 5e36810680adf57e

Comment: Have you also added the quotes per @user36303's answer? Thus 16 characters hex encoded, quoted "payment_id". Also, as you are wanting to use a random ID, you don't need to supply that parameter; it will default to a random ID.

Comment: Yes. I tried without quotes too. Now I removed payment_id parameter and I'm getting Method Not Found error. Also, address I'm typing as standard_address is taken from Monero GUI. Did I do it correctly?

Comment: I suspect it's your code then. It works fine for me. `curl -sd '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"make_integrated_address","params":{"payment_id":"5b67d705bbf72c77"}}' http://localhost:28084/json_rpc
`

Comment: Also, @user36303's comment is referring to the actual parameter name, not the value, which you have not quoted.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll try to take a look at my code again

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter name payment_id is not quoted.